# Apply jQuery.get() on dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

So, I have a dropdown menu using `<ul> <li> menu </li> <ul>`.

Now, one of the items has a large file size and I am thinking of applying jQuery.get() to reduce the loading amount and speed until it is clicked.

So, for example, I have the following menu:

```
 <ul>
    <li>
       <button type="button">
         <div class="_menu_title">Map</div>     
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown_menu_sub">
          <li class="dropdown_menu_sub_list">
                <div class="google_map"> Google map content goes here </div>                    
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here, when the `Map` button is clicked, then the google map will be shown in the menu. However, I noticed that it slows down the loading so I am thinking that unless the `Map` button is clicked, I don't want the map content to be loaded.

How can I apply a loading screen (to give user feedback that something is happening) and then load the content using the jQuery.get()?

[image]

Comment: jQuery.load will handle the loading part. The pending GUI is standard HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the loading-img per default and use the callback-function of jQuery's `.get()`-function to hide it when all the data is loaded:

```
$.get("/echo/html/", function (data) {
    $(".google_map").html(data);
    $('.dropdown_menu_sub_list > img').hide();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bz8h1prq/)**

Note: An error-handling would be good, because if the resource can't be loaded the loading-image just stays there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    //show loader here
    $('.google_map').html('loading image');
    $.get("/html/", function(data, status){
        if(status == "success"){
            //remove loader here and keep map data in google_map
            $('.google_map').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```